# mongodb nested values sort using java

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting

my mongoDB collections contains following documents

```
{
  "diskUtilization" : [
    {
        "usePercentage" : "12%",
        "mountedOn" : "Mounted",
        "available" : "Available",
        "blocks" : "1K-blocks",
        "used" : "1238921",
        "fileSystem" : "Filesystem"
    },
    {
        "usePercentage" : "19%",
        "mountedOn" : "/",
        "available" : "5617932",
        "blocks" : "7223800",
        "used" : "1238920",
        "fileSystem" : "/dev/sda1"
    },
    {
        "usePercentage" : "1%",
        "mountedOn" : "/dev",
        "available" : "500436",
        "blocks" : "500440",
        "used" : "4",
        "fileSystem" : "udev"
    }

}
```

now I want sort data according to used key's so my java code as below

```
DBCursor cur = coll.find().sort(new BasicDBObject("diskUtilization.used", -1)).limit(100);
```

but above cursor results not display data sorting order because of given key values in string format. How I can convert  mongo string values to int and then sort using java code or there any other method to sort string values?

Comment: why don't you add the same field as an int (or even replace the existent key) with a simple script? Seems to be much more effective than using an inefficient query. Of course this is not a solution if your data changes very fast - then you should maybe work on the inserts. If you can't, you have to stick to the answer given below and do the sorting by hand in your querying app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will have to do it yourself.

From the shell you can issue something such as:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) 
{
    doc.diskUtilization.map(function(sub) {
        sub.usePercentage=parseInt(sub.usePercentage);
    })
    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

Note that this simple JavaScript code doesn't check for correctness, for example that the diskUtilization array exists. You will have to add such validations yourself.